# Mac automatically restarts after shutdown

Tags: macos, shutdown, restart

I was using Win 10 on my 2017 21.5" iMac before, but formatted it and installed Mac Mojave again. Here `format` means I've formatted the data disk as well as system disk, merged all partitions and make only one volume. And installed Mojave.

Now if I select "Shutdown" in the Finder menu the Mac always automatically restarts instead. I am using power button to shutdown the computer. Sometimes, the computer restarts itself - without any action. Weird.

How can I fix or diagnose this?

Comment: This is a *clean* install of Mojave or did you restore from backup?  Did you restore your data from backup (like in Migration Assistant)?

Comment: This is a clean install, yes. I formatted my harddisk and installed with mojave USB.

Comment: No, no data and the computer is empty right now. Just installed mojave and no other actions so far.

Comment: Ok.  That tells me you didn’t bring over any “suspect” software.  Now, using a Terminal enter this command `sudo poweroff`. This will shutdown the computer so be sure your apps are closed with everything saved that needs to be saved.

Comment: sudo: poweroff: command not found

Comment: Sorry...gave you the BSD command.  Try `sudo shutdown -h now`

Comment: I tried, and it restarts as always.

Comment: Reset your [NVRAM](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204063) and your [SMC](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201295).  That command should have forced your Mac to power off - since it didn't, there's an issue with power management.  Don't do both at once...do one see if it fixes it.  If not, do the other and test again.

Comment: Yes, the command turned off the computer but restarts again.

Comment: So do I need to reset my NVRAM first?

Comment: ```Settings that can be stored in NVRAM include sound volume, display resolution, startup-disk selection, time zone, and recent kernel panic information.``` - this is NVRAM description, but I don't see any related with power settings.

Comment: Is it okay to do this really?

Comment: Try SMC first and it's perfectly OK to reset them.

Comment: Okay. I will let . you know

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/103063/discussion-between-o-o-and-allan).

Comment: Do you have any peripherals connected that might be somehow sending a boot signal to the Mac? For example, I _think_ some battery UPS units can power machines on… like if they're recovering from a power outage.

Comment: Sudden reboots could be caused by faulty ram. But it wouldn't cause the Shutdown to reboot instead.... Did resetting the pram and smc do anything?

Comment: @Sam There is no peripherals on my computer. This is a desktop computer with only keyboard and mouse.

Comment: @Yilk81 I've reset the SMC and still nothing happens.

Comment: I know this is a clean install, but check that system preferences -> energy saver -> start automatically after power failure is not checked (that setting is only visible on desktop macs).  Might be worth checking it and then unchecking it.

Comment: In MacOS 10.15 there is also a system preferences -> energy saver -> schedule button to schedule power ons.  Should be nothing there because it is a fresh install, but check anyway if that control exists in 10.14.

Comment: I’ll also suggest a fresh install of MacOS 10.15 Catalina, but that’s just a “hope” that the new OS will “clean up something”.  Side effect is that your 32-bit apps will be history.

Comment: Catalina is not working on my computer. :(

Comment: There is no ```start automatically after power failure```.  [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BTKhO.png)

Comment: Can you revert to Mojave to see if the problem goes away?  Did you reset the NVRAM?

Comment: Does the shutdown work in safe boot?

Comment: What do you mean? @Yilk81

Comment: @Allan Yes, reset the NVRAM as well - still :(

Comment: Boot your mac into safe boot mode (start the mac while holding down the shift button) and while in safe boot try and shut down the mac and see if it works as it should. 
https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201262

Comment: @Yilk81 - it’s a clean install, meaning there are no 3rd party apps, kexts, or processes running.  If the problem exists on a clean install, we have to look deeper.  In this case I’m waiting to see if going back to a previous OS has any effect.  Catalina is filled with bugs and idiosyncrasies that makes no sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used to work as an Apple technician and I'v had several Macs that describe your issue, but they were only laptops. The issue with them was liquid damaged. Now you thinking how the h'll can an iMac get liquid damaged, but I can tell you, I'v actually seen it myself. So it's possible but maybe not in your case.

I recommend to let an Apple technician look at it. Water damage causes a fault in the circuitry, but the same fault can happen from other causes or just rare breakage.

Comment: But here is a question. I've got some friends who are using the same computer and the same OS, everybody has got the same issue. All are damaged?

Comment: What circuitry would need to be damaged to prevent ACPI from telling the SMC to power off the machine?  If there was actual damage as you describe, it’s much, much more likely (orders of magnitude more) that the Mac would not turn on in the first place.

Comment: @Lumi Could you tell me the exact example what you've experienced in the past?

Comment: I'v had several MacBook Airs that have been exposed to some kind of liquid. People came in with them because they where afraid for it to get worse or something.. but one thing I noticed was actually that some of them couldn't shutdown, even though I selected Shutdown in the menu. They immediately started again (looked like it rebooted).. I removed battery and plugged power in and they auto started.

Comment: And about the liquid damaged iMac, the guy who had it said: The next day it was all fogged inside the screen.. he had his iMac next to a window, I don't know how close/far from it was or if he left the window open while it was rained outside, we couldn't know, he was assured that the window was closed so we had to believe him. The iMac was still working, we cleaned it and I haven't heard anything from him

Comment: @O.o have you sent your iMac to Apple for screening?

Comment: Send screenshot of my hardware??